# How to Insert from HTML/PHP Data into MySQL Database using jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I don't know how to insert form data into MySQL via jQuery

my html :

```
 Sendungstyp
 
 <select id="st">
<option  value="">Auswahlen</option>
    <option value="1">3kg</option>
    <option value="15">10kg</option>
    <option value="12">20kg</option>
    <option value="10">50kg</option>
</select>
Zeitoption
 <select id="zt">
<option  value="">Auswahlen</option>
    <option value="1">Classic</option>
    <option value="2">Direkt Fahrt</option>

</select>


Select bezirk <select id="vta">
<option  value="">Vrom</option>
    <option value="4.3">1010</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>


<select id="vtaa">
<option  value="">To</option>
    <option value="4.3">1010</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

    Total <input type="text" id="total" > Euro
```

jQuery that I have to extract the data:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
    $("#st").on('change', function() {
  updatePrice();
});

    $("#zt").on('change', function() {
  updatePrice();
});


    $("#vta").on('change', function() {
  updatePrice();
});
$("#vtaa").on('change', function() {
  updatePrice();
});


function updatePrice() {
    st = $("#st").val();
    zt = $("#zt").val();
  vta = $("#vta").val();
  vtaaa = $("#vtaa").val();
  total = (+vta) + (+vtaaa)+(+zt)+(+st);
  $("#total").val(total);
}
</script>
```

I know it's not a complicated problem but I don't know how to solve it. I tried several options but I did not succeed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Technically, there is no way to "insert form data into MySql via jQuery". What is done is to pass data to a Web Page, like a PHP Script, that can process the Form data passed to it into the MySQL Database. jQuery can assist by posting the data in the background to the PHP Page, this is what AJAX is.

Comment: $st = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['st']);
$zt = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['zt']);
 

$sql = "INSERT INTO auftrag ( st,zt) VALUES ('$st', '$zt')"; so ? @Twisty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing data to the web server, you would setup a HTML form like so:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This HTML code tells the browser to create a new HTTP POST and transmit the data to a relative page, update.php. A little like this:

```
update.php?myName=John%20Smith
```

When the HTTP Request is submitted, the browser will load the new page. The page will then need to process the details.

```
<?php
$postData = $_POST['myName'];
echo $postData;
?>
```

Your script will be more complex, this is just an example.

AJAX uses JavaScript to create the HTTP Request and submit it without having to load or refresh the page.

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post($(this).attr("action"), { myName: $("#myName").val() }, function(results){
    alert("Thank you " + result + ".");
  });
});
<script>
```

This jQuery script has been added and will be executed when the Form is submitted, the User presses "Send". The script will tell the browser to create a HTTP POST Request and send it to the PHP. There is a Callback function that will handle the returned data. From the User experience,they will click "Send" and get a response without the page refreshing.

Comment: Please note you have an typo in form method ppst.

Comment: @mrSotirow thank you for catching that!! I will correct it.